# Function to check data values against a .txt file in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (raw.data) containing data about multiple shells sampled in a survey, with one row for every shell sampled.

```
  Site     Sample         Species     Length (mm)
Site A          A       Species A              10
Site A          A       Species A              20
Site A          B       Species A               6
Site A          B       Species B              10
```

I have a .txt file containing species names and expected Min and Max length data for each species. I would like to write a short function to check the lengths in the raw.data against the Min and Max lengths in the .txt file for each species. If a value is out of the range I would like an error message telling me which rows have the problems.

I am quite new to R and have very little experience with functions so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Where are we starting from? Do you know how to read a text file into a data frame? That's step 1, and we don't know if you know that. You should be able to learn that from basic R documentation.

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned that. Yes the text file has been read in as a dataframe called ln.list.

Comment: Can you show some expected output based on the example

Comment: @akrun for example if the text file has a Min length set for Species A of 8 mm then the error message would say something along the lines of: 1322 (row number) Site A B Species A 6

Comment: Please update it in your post using the edit option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can join the data frames, a simple logical test should give you what you need.

```
Reference <- 
"Species,min,max\n
Species A,0,10 \n
Species B,5,15 \n
Species C,10,20"

Reference <- read.csv(textConnection(Reference),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Species <- 
"Site,Sample,Species,Length\n
Site A,A,Species A,10 \n
Site A,A,Species A,20\n
Site A,B,Species A,6\n
Site A,B,Species B,10"

Species <- read.csv(textConnection(Species),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
Species_Ref <- left_join(Species, Reference,
                         by = c("Species" = "Species")) %>%
  mutate(in_range = Length >= min & Length <= max)
```